# Accidentally added milk to my Graham cracker crust mix

Tags: substitutions, cheesecake

Can I bake all the ingredients together in a no bake cheesecake box bc I totally messed up and added the flippin milk in with the step 1! The melted butter, Graham cracker crust and sugar! Ugh help me please! I was looking forward to this cheesecake!!

Comment: I suspect that there was so much milk that it’s going to make the Graham crackers soggy unless you bind it up or drain it off somehow.  I’d be inclined to immediate strain it, then try adding the gelatin and such in to bind the liquid, then mix the crumbs in, and cool the whole thing… so it’s more a pudding / parfait type thing

Comment: Joe: I'd put that in as an answer, it's the best that the OP is going to get.

Comment: I'd pour it into a new crust or use it as a swirl in unbaked brownies. And then bake it. Consider the graham cracker crumbs seasoning.

Comment: @Joe I might even strain the crumbs, wrap them in cheesecloth and squeeze gently, then bake them to dry them.  But only if I was desperate to avoid wasting them and had the oven on anyway (quite likely if it's a baked cheesecake).

Answer (score 1):

As this is a no-bake cheesecake, you probably aren't in too much trouble. Just make a new crust, complete the filling, and fill and chill as normal. The texture will be sandy from the graham cracker crumbs and may be drier than usual but should be acceptable.